# Joomla template not showing properly on IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, templates, joomla

I have installed Black&White free template from http://templatesforjoomla.eu/free-joomla-1.5-templates/blackandwhite-free-joomla-1.5-template.html 
I really like this template and want to use it but I found a problem. It is not properly displayed on IE8 (it is said to work on IE7+). These are my problems that you also can see on the demo site

1. The slider works ok on everything except IE - only the picture is displayed without the text next to it
2. When the submenus on the top reach the picture in the slider - they hide behind it

I have some experience with joomla but IE has always be my nightmare. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set up conditional css just for IE8, that way you could fix all css issues .. note that IE8 still holds some restrictions like not rendering CSS3 or media queries ..

you can read more about IE conditional comments here http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer